# Javascript replace content before visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, replacewith, insertafter

I want to replace certain nodes with different HTML if javascript is enabled.
My problem is that for a short moment the old code is visible and then the replaced element shows up.
What would be a text-book solution for that? Where do I need to put the javascript, preferably jquery? Is it possible anyway?
No example code , just imagine a page with a bunch of deeply nested nodes..

Comment: please add your all your code that is relevant to your question

Comment: Have you considered wrapping the 'no-JavaScript' content in a [`<noscript>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) element?

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
<noscript></noscript>
```

tags to display content that is shown when js is disabled

Comment: forgot I can't simply post tags and not format as code

Answer (score 0):

DOM operations are pretty slow and in some corner cases you may experience the blink of the old content. I see two solutions:

1. Use a preloader screen, e.g.: [Create A Custom Preloading Screen](https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-custom-preloading-screen/). This way you can perform all manipulations on the DOM elements in the background.
2. If the content of your page is static you can use `<noscript></noscript>` tags and this way set the content for both situations (JavaScript enabled, JavaScript disabled).